# Logging in with multiple types of info

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I'm trying to let users log in with multiple columns (e.g. ID, email, phone). If one fails, it checks the next column.

I would like to minimise my `if` and `else` statements. Is there better way of doing it?

```
$email = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $ssn='';$badgenumber='';$ophone='';$fphone='';$pager='';


        if(preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/",$email['email']) == 1 && strlen($email['email']) < 6){
            $ssn = $request->only('ssn', 'password');
            $badgenumber = $request->only('badgenumber', 'password');
        }

        if(preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/",$email['email']) == 1 && strlen($email['email']) > 6){
            $ophone = $request->only('ophone', 'password');
            $fphone = $request->only('fphone', 'password');
            $pager = $request->only('pager', 'password');
        }

        if(filter_var($email['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
            $email ='';

        $error = 1;

        try {
            // verify the $email and create a token for the user

            if ($error == 1 && $email) {
                $error = 0;
                if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($email)) {
                    $error = 1;
                }
            }
            if ($error == 1 && $ssn) {
                $error = 0;
                if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($ssn)) {
                    $error = 1;
                }
            }
            if ($error == 1 && $badgenumber) {
                $error = 0;
                if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($badgenumber)) {
                    $error = 1;
                }
            }
            if ($error == 1 && $ophone) {
                $error = 0;
                if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($ophone)) {
                    $error = 1;
                }
            }
            if ($error == 1 && $fphone) {
                $error = 0;
                if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($fphone)) {
                    $error = 1;
                }
            }
            if ($error == 1 && $pager) {
                $error = 0;
                if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($pager)) {
                    $error = 1;
                }
            }

            if($error == 1){
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }

        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is the backend to a login request, I assume that you expect just 2 inputs, the password and one of the others.  So why not use the following:

```
//gets an array of all inputs: email & pass or ssn & pass or phone & pass...    
$credentials = $request->all(); 

try{
    if(!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)){
        return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
    }

} catch (JWTException $e){
    return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
}
```

> i would like to minimise my if and else what would you guys recommend?

**Hint:** If you find yourself doing something over and over and over, you probably need a loop. Since this is a login form and that you expect just 1 variable besides the password, don't have so many vars in your script: `$email`, `$ssn`, `$pager`, `badgenumber`, `ophone`, `fphone`, `ssn`... just use `$identifier`.  If you really need to cycle through all possibilities build an array and loop until you find the one the user submitted:

```
$possibilities = ['email','ssn','badgenumber','ophone'...];
$identifier = '';
foreach ($possibilities as $i){
    if($request->has($i)){
        $identifier = $request->input($i);
        break; //exit the foreach loop b/c we've found the identifier
    }
}
$credentials = [$identifier, $request->input('password')];
```

Then you can attempt to create the token with those credentials.  Beware I've never used Laravel, but I wrote my answer after going over [this helpful page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests) on how to access requests.

Quick sidenote: I notice that you have a check that can be true only if email has length < 6, and another that can be true only if email has length > 6.  What if email has length===6 ?

Comment: check my question i've made changes thanks to your example :)

Comment: check my answer, this is what i did from your example.

Answer (score 0):

here is what i've done.

```
$rules = [
            'email' => 'email',
            'ssn' => 'integer|digits_between:3,4',
            'badgenumber' => 'integer|digits_between:3,4',
            'ophone' => 'integer|digits_between:9,11',
            'fphone' => 'integer|digits_between:9,11',
            'pager' => 'integer|digits_between:9,11',
        ];

        $token ='';
        try {

            foreach($rules as $k => $r){

                $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    $k => $r,
                ]);

                if (!$validator->fails() && $request->has($k) && 
                    $token = JWTAuth::attempt($request->only($k, 'password'))) {
                    break;
                }

            }


            if(!$token){
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }

        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }
```

Comment: I don't think you should create the `Validator` once for every rule. Why not call `Validator::make($request->all(),$rules)` one time before the `foreach` loop? Then you would use `if` to stop processing a bad form: `if($validator->fails())`, respond with invalid form input error. Below that you can have the `foreach($rules)...` without worrying about validation.  This way you create the validator and you check its fail-state only once.